# Linux packages API

Tags: linux, debian, redhat-enterprise-linux

I’m trying to build an API that gives information about a particular package across various distributions. For example if a user wanted to query ‘python’ to see what’s available in the repository they would get a result similar to “apt search python” from the API.

[Launchpad](https://help.launchpad.net/API/) is a good example where someone can search packages. However, this only works for Ubuntu.

I understand that making a generic solution to satisfy all linux distros would be incredibly unfeasible due to various different package managers. However, are there any strategies in achieving what I described in Debian (using apt) or Red Hat (using yum) distros?

Answer (score 0):

The strategy is "do what a package manager does". Most Linux package managers simply download a list of packages in certain well-defined format (e.g. `apt update` downloads plain ASCII files which are [explained here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format)), and most do it through regular HTTP.

As long as you know the URL of a repository and understand its format, you can just do the same thing – download the package database from that URL, parse it according to the distro's specification, and import into e.g. your local SQL database that acts as the "backend" for the API.

This would immediately give support for all distros which share the same package manager (e.g. an Apt database parser will support Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, Deepin, Kali...) without relying on any outside infrastructure besides what the distro must already provide to its users anyway.